# How to run a program more than once without having to repeatedly run it?

Tags: python

My code is below. I am writing a Minecraft program that randomly places 5 blocks in a single program. I am having trouble in the for statement, as I am trying to place 5 blocks randomly without placing one block and having to run the program 5 times. I'm not sure what to put in the for statement either. Any help or suggestions are always appreciated. * The code below the def function statement are indented.

```
def placeRandomBlocks():
    global diamond_x, diamond_y, diamond_z
    pos = mc.player.getTilePos() # get player position
    for i in range(0, 5):
```

Comment: Please add code for placing one block to your question.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You may want to modify your question and title.  It sounds like what you really want to do is run `place_block()` (or whatever it's called) 5 times rather than run the program 5 times.  You should be able to search `python for loop` and get a good tutorial on how to write one.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you define your method for placing a single block randomly.

```
from random import randint

def placeRandomBlock():
    x, y, z = mc.player.getPos()
    mc.setBlock(randint(0,9) + x, randint(0,9) + y, z, 1)
```

and then you need to call that method, within a loop to place multiple blocks.

```
for block in range(0, 5):
    placeRandomBlock()
```